# Label set x and y-axes to cartesian coordinate on an image

Tags: matlab, axis, cartesian-coordinates

I have a 2032 x 2032 image (image1) I am trying to display using

```
figure(1)
imagesc(image1);
```

The x and y-axes are displaying the pixel count (i.e. 1-2032) with the smallest value being in the upper left-hand corner and the greatest value in the lower right-hand corner.

How do I set the x and y-axes to a cartesian coordinate setup ranging from (-1016 to 1016) with (0,0) located in the center?

Comment: Did you try `help image` to see what options you have available to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the axis values in `imagesc`:

```
imagesc(-1016:1015,-1016:1015,image1):
```